# REST GET Design Issue

Tags: java, rest, get, jersey

I am currently new to RESTful Architecture and using Jersey to practice. i am facing difficulty in implementing GET operation.following REST naming/URL convention for getting a particular customer from the server would be

GET http://www.example.com/customers/33245

However while designing client side how would the client know that specific id belong that specific customer as it would be in the database linked with the server and hidden from client. One implementation i think of is to extract all the information regarding all the customers from the database and store in the client but i believe it kills the whole purpose. what should be the optimum way for searching for a specific customer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such an URL is used for getting a customer that you already know. Not for searching customers.

For searching customers, you would typically use an URL like

```
http://www.example.com/customers?name=Doe&firstname=John
```

This would list all the customers named John Doe, and the list would contain, for every customer, the ID of the found customer. The client would then use this ID to invoke the URL in your question and get detailed information about this customer.

You can of course use any query criteria you want, or allow accessing customers by other means.

If you think about it, that's exactly how web searchingworks. You don't know the URL of a page, you search for this page by keywords on Google, which returns a list of results containing the title, description and URL of thepage, then you use the URL to actually access the page.

Comment: I'll just add that it's an even better practice that you return a list of URLs to each customer named John Doe instead of a list of IDs. That way the client doesn't even have to create the URL it just uses what's been created by the server.